# Reset password laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Creé un modelo propio y modifique el provider para usar el modelo mio llamado Admin en config>auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

y mi modelo le agregue lo siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new MyResetPassword($token));
    }  
}
```

y ahora debo crear como una notificacion algo asi? es que no entiendo mucho la documentacion, esta es la que estoy viendo https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passwords

el punto es que en mi login tengo un enlace que dice resetear su password entonces al dar clic quiero que me envie el link para reestablecer la password

Comment: La recuperación de contraseña es sencilla, puedes seguir esta documentación o este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_a02Twp4Gc0)(esta sobre la version 5.1). Suerte con esto

Comment: ¿qué es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas un poco perdido.
Según entiendo lo unico que cambiaste fue el modelo, no se autentican los usuarios sino los administradores.
Mas allá de eso podrías incluso tener las 2 opciones corriendo simultaneamente.
Es un tema complicado de explicar pero no es para nada complicado en si.
 1- Necesitas agregar el trait `Notifiable` a tu modelo.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

}
```

2- Tenés que crear una notificación, SOLO en el caso de que desees cambiar la notificación por defecto y en este caso si, necesitarías agregar el metodo.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\MyResetPassword; 
// php artisan make:notification MyResetPassword

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new MyResetPassword($token));
    }  
}
```

3- Después si el caso es que querés tener una doble autenticación, osea con usuarios y con admins ahi se complica un poco porque tenes que hacer unas cuantas cosas mas.
 a. Agregar un nuevo guard en config/auth
 b. Agregar un nuevo provider en config/auth
 c. Agregar un nuevo password en config/auth
 ....
 Te dejo un tutorial que encontré [Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5.4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M&list=PLwAKR305CRO9S6KVHMJYqZpjPzGPWuQ7Q)